# Unauthorized request on Mac Build Host

Tags: build, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Upon building a Xamarin.iOS project from Visual Studio the build process fails almost immediately with no error in the Build output.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Testp.App, Configuration: Ad-Hoc iPhone ------
1>  Generated session id: 9318ce286318f5c0a9b194a8a9d81102
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Showing the output from Mac Server Log I can see the following error

```
[08-Sep-2014 11:46:36] Handling with command: [Default: CommmandUrl=] (16)
[08-Sep-2014 11:46:36] Attempting to acquire command execution lock, timeout set to 00:10:00
[08-Sep-2014 11:46:36] Error: Invalid authorization data
[08-Sep-2014 11:46:36] Error: Unauthorized request from 10.10.0.xxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a mismatch in versions between the software installed on the Mac and the software installed on the PC. I had been updating the Xamarin.iOS software via Visual Studio without updating it on the Mac. To solve this problem I loaded Xamarin Studio, and opened the `Check for updates...` dialog.

[image: Xamarin Update]

After updating and restarting the software I was able to reconnect Visual Studio to my build server and complete the build. The lesson being it pays to load up Xamarin Studio and update, even if you never use it to code, after updating Xamarin.iOS

Comment: Thanks for sharing your update on this.  I'll have to keep that in mind as well.  :-)